# Hibernate merge executes 11000 selects before update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on a JSF/JPA project with the Sakila Database on MySQL with Hibernate. When I want to merge a customer object into the DB, it takes 20 seconds. I assume it has to do with the mapping of my Entity Class but I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.
Here is my Customer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable, IEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private Short customerId;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "active")
private boolean active;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "create_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createDate;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "last_update")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastUpdate;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerId")
private List<Rental> rentalList;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerId")
private List<Payment> paymentList;

@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "address_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Address addressId;

@JoinColumn(name = "store_id", referencedColumnName = "store_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Store storeId;

//Constructor 

//getter_setter
}
```

And in my CustomerService ejb I call the merge function:

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class CustomerService {

@PersistenceContext(name = "sakila")
EntityManager em;

public String merge(IEntity entity) {
    try {
        em.merge(entity);
        return "success";
    }catch(Exception e){
        return "failure";
        }
    }
}
```

In the log I can see that hibernate executes 11037 select statements just like this one

```
 select
    paymentlis0_.customer_id as customer5_11_0_,
    paymentlis0_.payment_id as payment_1_11_0_,
    paymentlis0_.payment_id as payment_1_11_1_,
    paymentlis0_.amount as amount2_11_1_,
    paymentlis0_.customer_id as customer5_11_1_,
    paymentlis0_.last_update as last_upd3_11_1_,
    paymentlis0_.payment_date as payment_4_11_1_,
    paymentlis0_.rental_id as rental_i6_11_1_,
    paymentlis0_.staff_id as staff_id7_11_1_,
    rental1_.rental_id as rental_i1_12_2_,
    rental1_.customer_id as customer5_12_2_,
    rental1_.inventory_id as inventor6_12_2_,
    rental1_.last_update as last_upd2_12_2_,
    rental1_.rental_date as rental_d3_12_2_,
    rental1_.return_date as return_d4_12_2_,
    rental1_.staff_id as staff_id7_12_2_,
    customer2_.customer_id as customer1_5_3_,
    customer2_.active as active2_5_3_,
    customer2_.address_id as address_8_5_3_,
    customer2_.create_date as create_d3_5_3_,
    customer2_.email as email4_5_3_,
    customer2_.first_name as first_na5_5_3_,
    customer2_.last_name as last_nam6_5_3_,
    customer2_.last_update as last_upd7_5_3_,
    customer2_.store_id as store_id9_5_3_,
    inventory3_.inventory_id as inventor1_9_4_,
    inventory3_.film_id as film_id3_9_4_,
    inventory3_.last_update as last_upd2_9_4_,
    inventory3_.store_id as store_id4_9_4_,
    staff4_.staff_id as staff_id1_13_5_,
    staff4_.active as active2_13_5_,
    staff4_.address_id as address10_13_5_,
    staff4_.email as email3_13_5_,
    staff4_.first_name as first_na4_13_5_,
    staff4_.last_name as last_nam5_13_5_,
    staff4_.last_update as last_upd6_13_5_,
    staff4_.password as password7_13_5_,
    staff4_.picture as picture8_13_5_,
    staff4_.store_id as store_i11_13_5_,
    staff4_.username as username9_13_5_,
    staff5_.staff_id as staff_id1_13_6_,
    staff5_.active as active2_13_6_,
    staff5_.address_id as address10_13_6_,
    staff5_.email as email3_13_6_,
    staff5_.first_name as first_na4_13_6_,
    staff5_.last_name as last_nam5_13_6_,
    staff5_.last_update as last_upd6_13_6_,
    staff5_.password as password7_13_6_,
    staff5_.picture as picture8_13_6_,
    staff5_.store_id as store_i11_13_6_,
    staff5_.username as username9_13_6_,
    address6_.address_id as address_1_1_7_,
    address6_.address as address2_1_7_,
    address6_.address2 as address3_1_7_,
    address6_.city_id as city_id8_1_7_,
    address6_.district as district4_1_7_,
    address6_.last_update as last_upd5_1_7_,
    address6_.phone as phone6_1_7_,
    address6_.postal_code as postal_c7_1_7_,
    store7_.store_id as store_id1_14_8_,
    store7_.address_id as address_3_14_8_,
    store7_.last_update as last_upd2_14_8_,
    store7_.manager_staff_id as manager_4_14_8_,
    store8_.store_id as store_id1_14_9_,
    store8_.address_id as address_3_14_9_,
    store8_.last_update as last_upd2_14_9_,
    store8_.manager_staff_id as manager_4_14_9_ 
from
    payment paymentlis0_ 
left outer join
    rental rental1_ 
        on paymentlis0_.rental_id=rental1_.rental_id 
left outer join
    customer customer2_ 
        on rental1_.customer_id=customer2_.customer_id 
left outer join
    inventory inventory3_ 
        on rental1_.inventory_id=inventory3_.inventory_id 
left outer join
    staff staff4_ 
        on rental1_.staff_id=staff4_.staff_id 
inner join
    staff staff5_ 
        on paymentlis0_.staff_id=staff5_.staff_id 
inner join
    address address6_ 
        on staff5_.address_id=address6_.address_id 
inner join
    store store7_ 
        on staff5_.store_id=store7_.store_id 
left outer join
    store store8_ 
        on staff5_.staff_id=store8_.manager_staff_id 
where
    paymentlis0_.customer_id=?
```

It takes 20 seconds before Hibernate finally sends the update query

```
Information:   Hibernate: 
update
    customer 
set
    active=?,
    address_id=?,
    create_date=?,
    email=?,
    first_name=?,
    last_name=?,
    last_update=?,
    store_id=? 
where
    customer_id=?
```

I assume my mapping is wrong and customer is configured to be lazily loaded. Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously in order to merge, JPA implementation (Hibernate here) needs to know if there are any changes made to detached (or lazy, not yet fetched) entities or not, thus it is checking its state with `SELECT`. Since you are cascadig (with CascadeType.ALL) your merge to all related entities - whole graph is refreshed.

Either do not cascade merges, or insteed merge use JPQL (or CriteriAPI) update if you need only to update parent entity disregarding it children.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my problem. I think this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) might contain useful information as well.